# Spectrum of operator in infinite dimensional hilbert space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

We know that if a complex hilbert space $H$ is separable, then for every compact set $K$, there exists a bounded linear operator $T : H \to H$ s.t $\sigma (T) = K$. My question is if this still holds if $H$ is not separable. Can you construct such an operator? Thanks

Comment: Modulo adding zero to the spectrum, answer is trivially yes.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean? How you construct operator T?

Comment: You can just construct the operator on a separable subspace then extend by zero on the orthogonal complement.

Comment: Never mind, extend by $p \in K$ rather than $0$ on the orthogonal complement as John's answer below.

Comment: @user61581: I think the comment you wrote sometimes in the comment of my answer is valid. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is true only when $K$ is not finite.

Pick $p\in K$ such that $p$ is a limit point of $K$. Let $L$ be a separable closed subspace of $H$, let $A: L \to L$ be an operator with $\sigma(A) = K$. Let $L^\perp$ be the orthogonal complement such that $H = L \oplus L^\perp$. Define $\tilde A: H\to H$,

$$\tilde A(l + l^\perp) = Al + p l^\perp\ .$$

Claim: $\sigma(\tilde A) = \sigma(A)$.

Let $z\notin \sigma( A)$. Then $(A - z)^{-1} : L \to L$ exists as bounded operator. As $z\neq p$, define 
$$B(l + l^\perp) = (A - z)^{-1}l + \frac{1}{p-z} l^\perp\ .$$

Then $B$ is bounded and $B = (\tilde A  -z)^{-1}$. Thus $z\notin \sigma(\tilde A)$ and $\sigma(\tilde A) \subset \sigma(A)$.

Now let $z\notin \sigma(\tilde A)$, $z\neq p$. Then $(\tilde A - z)^{-1}$ exists as bounded linear operator on $H$. Let $B$ be the restriction of $(\tilde A - z)^{-1}$ to $L$. Let $y\in L$, then

$$y = (\tilde A - z)B y = (\tilde A - z) (a + a^\perp) = (A-z)a + (p-z)a^\perp$$

(we write $By = a+ a^\perp$). Thus $y = (A-z)a$ and $(p-z)a^\perp = 0$. The condition implies that $a^\perp=0$ and hence $B$ has image in $L$. Thus $B$ is the inverse of $A - z$ and $z\notin \sigma(A)$. Hence

$$\rho(\tilde A) \setminus \{p\} \subset \rho(A) \Rightarrow \sigma(A) \subset \sigma(\tilde A) \cup \{p\}$$

Thus $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(\tilde A) \cup \{p\} \subset \sigma(A) \cup \{p\} = \sigma(A)$ as $p\in \sigma(A)$. Hence $\sigma(A) =\sigma(\tilde A) \cup \{p\}$, or

$$\sigma(A) \setminus\{p\} = \sigma(\tilde A)\ .$$

As $p$ is a limit point of $K$ and $\sigma(\tilde A)$ is closed, we have

$$\sigma(A) = \sigma(\tilde A)\ .$$

Comment: Suppose $p$ is not a limit point in $K$, but a singleton, i.e {p}. I think it's easy to prove that $p \in \sigma(\tilde {A})$.

Comment: Yes, actually you need consider only when $K$ is finite. That would be easy I suppose.